# Reference for expectation and variance of the product of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, variance, expected-value

Given two **independent** random variables X, Y, the expectation of their product XY is:

$\mathrm{E}[XY] = \mathrm{E}[X]\cdot\mathrm{E}[Y]$

Similarly, the variance of the product of these variables is:

$\mathrm{Var}[XY] = \mathrm{Var}[X]\cdot \mathrm{Var}[Y] + \mathrm{Var}[Y]( \mathrm{E}[X])^2 + \mathrm{Var}[X] (\mathrm{E}[Y])^2$

While proofs or sketches of proofs can be found online (even within this forum), I have been struggling to find a **citable reference** of the above formulas (i.e., a textbook or a paper). Can you provide a suitable reference?

Comment: You probably can find the result given as an exercise in quite a few textbooks, but I doubt there exists some references centered around this (rather anecdotical) application of the definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first formula for independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, sometimes called the product law of expectation, is not hard to find. It can be found in most undergrad probability and statistics textbooks. For instance, you can find it [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Es_VswEACAAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA160#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page 160 of *Introduction to the Theory of Statistics* by Mood-Graybill-Boes, 3rd edition.

The second formula, even if not included in the main material of textbooks, could be found as an exercise, like this one [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=NGPdBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page 89, problem I-32 of *Exercises in Probability* by T. Cacoullos.

Answer (score 0):

[On the Exact Variance of Products](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1960.10483369) by Leo A. Goodman, published in
Journal of the American Statistical Association, Volume 55, 1960 - Issue 292

is a peer-reviewed article focusing on this problem with the result for two independent variables stated in its Equation 2.

Comment: Have you read this paper at all ? It can also be found [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cga/var/2281592.pdf). Its main result is something totally different from the well-known $Var[XY]$ formula in OP.